# Виртуальный деструктор при наследовании

Tags: c++, деструктор

Класс наследует интерфейс, в котором деструктор объявлен виртуальным. Надо ли в своем классе явно объявлять деструктор виртуальным? Чтобы обеспечить вызов деструктора при работе через интерфейс.

```
class MyInterface{
public:
    virtual ~MyInterface(){};
    ...
}

class MyClass : public MyInterface{
public:
    ~MyClass(); //или же необходимо virtual ~MyClass();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Нет, не надо. Он уже и так виртуальный.

Начиная с 11-го стандарта, можно в данном случае использовать ключевое слово override. В таком случае, компилятор проверит, является ли деструктор базового класса (или переопределяемый метод в общем случае) виртуальным - и вы сможете отловить ситуацию, когда забыли сделать деструктор базового класса виртуальным.

Answer (score 2):

Нет, достаточно написать `virtual` в базовом классе.

Но чтобы точно документировать - для себя - лично я предпочитаю писать это `virtual`. Тогда вам не придется искать базовый класс, чтобы убедиться, что какая-то функция - виртуальна.

Comment: Можно и так, но `override` появилось в стандарте недавно, а вот `virtual` - очень давно :) Привычка.

Comment: не нужно писать в всех наследниках virtual - это может принести дополнительные чудо-баги.

Comment: @KoVadim А можно подробнее? Где это может привести к багам?

Comment: я такое видел. Человек добавил virtual, но сигнатуру ошибся. И в третьем наследовании ломал голову, почему работает криво, когда он по базовому обращается. Но есть ещё лучше. Потом он узнал о override и втулил все три слова (virtual override final) в одной строки. Но сигнатуру промазал...

Comment: @KoVadim А, ну так тут именно `virtual` в полной мере ни при чем - он бы сломал голову и без него :)

Comment: @KoVadim с сигнатурой деструктора сложно ошибиться :)

Comment: ну мало чего. народные умельцы и компилятор поправят ради фана.